# New keyword: why is the derived method not called?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have simple three classes:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Write()
    {
        Console.Write("A");
    }
}

class B:A
{
    public override void Write()
    {
        Console.Write("B");
    }
}

class C : B
{
    public new void Write()
    {
        Console.Write("C");
    }
}
```

And I am creating objects and calling their methods:

```
A a = new A();
a.Write();

A b = new C();
b.Write();

C c = new C();
c.Write();
```

And output will be: `ABC`

What I cannot understand is **why these code produces `B`?**:

```
A b = new C();
b.Write();
```

I thought that it should be `C`. However, I tested many times, and it is always `B`.

I understand that `A b = new C()` creates new object type of C. So output should be C. Or it is special behavior to call overridden method when we use it without casting?

Why does it happen? As we have not used any reference to `B` class.

Comment: Because that's how the new keyword works. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would work if you'd use `((C)b).Write();`

With the `new` keyword you're not overriding the `Write` method for C but rather creating a new method only defined for C. So for your C you actually have 2 methods with a method name `Write`.

```
A c = new C();

c.Write();          //Output "B", you're calling the overridden method    
((C)c).Write();     //Output "C", you're calling the method defined on C

//or

(c as C).Write();
```

The same happens when you would define c as `C`:

```
C c = new C();

c.Write();          //Output "C"    
((A)c).Write();     //Output "B"
```

In the first example you're calling the new method defined on C. In the second line you are calling the `Write` method from A, which is overridden by B, hence the output `"B"`.

**Edit:** (some more explanation)

Variable `c` is of type A, so that's what your compiler knows *"c is an instance of A"*, it is not known that it is actually of a more derived type. When you call the method `Write` on it, it will invoke the method defined on A (which is overriden by B). Your base class A has no knowledge of your new method defined on C (that's what `new` does, create a new method), so unless you cast it to C to let the compiler know about the actual, derived type of `c`, the method of your base class will be called.

Comment: Often called "member hiding" or "shadowing", use it sparingly and carefully - it can be quite jarring when you expect the code to do something else.

Comment: I am sorry for my dumb question, but why does these code `A b = new C(); b.Write();` call overriden method? I mean that `A b = new C()` creates new object type of `C`. So output should be `C`. Or it is special behavior to call overridden method when we use it without casting?

Comment: To access a method that is hiding another, you need a strongly-typed reference to the type that defines the hiding, not a base reference. The same rule also applies to explicitly implemented interfaces. It is basically not "proper" inheritance, so the inheritance hierarchy is not enforced in the same manner as a standard overridden method call.

Comment: @StepUp try it out with another method `WriteLine` that you *only* define on C, not on A or B. If you say `A c = new C()` the method `c.WriteLine()` won't be available to you until you cast. It won't show up in intellisense either.

Comment: Great article by Eric Lippert [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/21/method-hiding-apologia/) about when you should and (especially!) shouldn't use member hiding.

Comment: *StepUp try it out with another method WriteLine that you only define on C, not on A or B.* it is really true!:) But why?

Comment: Hard to explain but you say your variable `c` is of type `A`, so that's what your compiler knows "c is an instance of A", it isn't known that it is actually of a more derived type. When you call the method `Write` on it, it will invoke the method defined on A, which is actually overriden by B. Your base class `A` has no knowledge of your new method defined on C (exactly the same as with the `WriteLine` method, that's what `new` does, create a new method), so unless you cast it to `C` the method of your base class will be called.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck please, include your last comment to the answer. It is really useful!:)

Comment: @StepUp Edited it in :)

Comment: @AlexanderDerck It is really a brilliant answer! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I now its really late and does not answer the question, but i needed that behavior and just in case some else need it i'll share it.
To get that beheavior you need to use interfaces, for example

```
interface Writer{
 void write;
}

class A : Writer
{
    void Writer.Write()
    {
        Console.Write("A");
    }
}
```

And the same for the others. As you can see, you have to implement it explicity as well as call it explicity.

```
A c = new C();
((Writer) c).write()
```

;